# joint pdf setting up the integral

Tags: integration, statistics

Let $X$ and $Y$ have the joint pdf
$f_{x,y}(x,y)=2e^{-(x+y)}, 0<x<y, 0<y$. Find $P(Y<3X)$

my question is regarding setting up the integral: $\int_0^\infty\int_x^{3x}2e^{-x}e^{-y}dydx$

(1) i understand why the y integral is $0$ to infinity because it is given that $0<y$ however why is the $x$ integral from $x$ to $3x$, this is confusing especially the lower bound $x$, why not $0$?

(2) also why are the $dy$ and $dx$ switched, the formula has them written as $dxdy$, why is that and when is it appropriate to switch them this way?

edit: i think i might have answered my own question (1), the $x$ goes from $0$ to $y$ and $y$ goes to infinity therefore $x$ is integrated from $0$ to infinity, as far as $Y$, $Y$ is greater then $X$ and smaller then $3X$ therefore it is integrated from $X$ to $3X$. (can someone concur). But why are the $dxdy$ switched to $dydx$ is it because we are trying to find the prob. of $y$ and whatever we are trying to find must be the inner integral (still confused)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner integral is an integral in the vertical $y$ direction.  Note that the bound given in the joint pdf is $x < y$, while the bound sought after in the probability computation is $y < 3 x$, so the integration bound is $x < y < 3 x$; this probability is

$$2 \int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-x} \int_x^{3 x} dy \, e^{-y} = \frac12$$

Note how I wrote the integral so that it is clear which variable goes with which integral.  I do this to avoid the confusion you have experienced in how your integral is written - it is unclear which is inner and outer (aside from the limits dependent upon $x$).

To illustrate, I can switch the order of integration.  This involves solving for $x$ as a function of $y$: $x < y < 3 x \implies y/3 < x < y$.  The integral is then

$$2 \int_0^{\infty} dy \, e^{-y} \, \int_{y/3}^y dx \, e^{-x}$$

which you can show is $1/2$ as before.